# Brownian motion / ito's formula

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, finance

Little help is needed
Can I use geometric Brownian motion here?

The question I get:

$Let z=(z_t)$ be a one-dimensional standard Brownian motion and define the process
$y = ( y_t )$ by $y_t = z_t^2 − t$ .

1. Show that $y_t = 2t\int^t_0 z_udz_u$. 
   Hint: Notice that $y_t = g(z_t, t)$ where the function $g(x, t) =x^2−t$. Then apply Itˆo’s formula.
2. how that $E[y_t] = 0$ and that $var[y_t] = 2t^2$.

Comment: Not sure what *geometric* Brownian motion has to do with anything here. All you really need here is Ito's formula and the fact that the Ito integral of a sufficiently nice function is a martingale.

Comment: How would you solve this? Im confused how to handle $z^2_t$ and $2_t$

Comment: Use Ito's formula on $g$.

Comment: Wrong question + No personal input = Winning combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z$ is a one-dimensional standard Brownian motion - it is another name for the Wiener process. By the definition of Wiener process w have that $z_t - z_0$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $t$.

Applying the Ito's lemma to $y=g(t,x)=x^2-t$ one obtains

$$dg(t,z)=g_t(t,z)dt+g_z(t,z)dz+\frac{1}{2} g_{zz}(t,z)dt$$

so we have $dy=2zdz$, and if we rewrite this as a stochastic integral we have the desired result.

By definition $\mathrm{Var}(z_t)=E[z_t^2]-(E[z_t])^2=t$, 
while the martingale property of the Wiener process implies $E[z_t]=z_0=0$, consequently $E[z_t^2-t]=E[y_t]=0$.

Further calculation gives
$\mathrm{Var}(z_t^2-t)=E[(z_t^2-t)^2]-(E[z_t^2-t])^2=E[z_t^4]-2tE[z_t^2]+t^2.$
Since $E[z_t^4]$ is the 4th central moment of random variable with normal distribution so it is equal $3\mathrm{Var}(z_t)^2=3t^2$.

Pulling everything together: $\mathrm{Var}(z_t^2-t) = 3t^2 - 2t^2 + t^2 = 2t^2.$

Comment: So writting it as a stochastic integral, we get $2z_tdz_t=2∫_0^tz_tdz_t$